# Symfony2 Process doest't give feedback in real-time

Tags: php, symfony, symfony-2.1, symfony-process

my idea is to start a minecraft server with the [Symfony2 Process Class](http://api.symfony.com/2.1/Symfony/Component/Process/Process.html) and want to give feedback to me in real time. So, like described in the [Process cookbook part](http://symfony.com/doc/current/components/process.html), I try the following code:

```
$process = new Process('sudo java -jar -Xms512M -Xmx1G ../server/minecraft_server.jar');
    $process->setTimeout(null);
    $process->run(function ($type, $buffer) {
        if ('err' === $type) {
            echo 'ERR > '.$buffer;
        } else {
            echo 'OUT > '.$buffer;
        }
    });
```

Because of some permission issues with the apache2 user i modified the sudoers file with this:  `www-data      ALL = (myspecialUser) NOPASSWD: /usr/bin/java`
so the www-data user can run the java command.

The server is starting in the background, but my problem is now that I'm not getting any real-time output.  Only if I shutdown (or kill) the minecraft server process I get the output.

Any suggestions how to get a real-time output?

Comment: Where is the output going to? If it's a file, then you should read that file content from an action and return it, then call it periodically from ajax to have it on your page.

Comment: Working solution will be redirect output to standard error. For example this will work for you: fprintf(STDERR, "ERR > %s", $buffer); But i'm not sure if it's the best solution

Comment: no, that doesn't work for me. I think I'll write a symfony task that starts the minecraft server (output on console is working)

Comment: I have the same problem local on OSX the command run for the idle timeout... and on ubuntu the process starts and don't close after the execution. Any solutions?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of calling the run() method, you should try with the start() one:

```
$process = new Process('sudo java -jar -Xms512M -Xmx1G ../server/minecraft_server.jar');
$process->setTimeout(null);
$process->start(function ($type, $buffer));

echo 'OUT >' . $process->getOutput();
```

http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/Process/Process.html#method_start

http://api.symfony.com/master/Symfony/Component/Process/Process.html#method_getOutput

Comment: Neither run() nor start() works for me. In both cases, the callbacks are executed not until the process finishes.

Comment: EDIT: Okay it seems like a Windows bug where fread blocks further execution. "Process::start is not working correctly because any call to a method that read pipes is blocking", for more details have a look at https://github.com/symfony/symfony/issues/9755